# How do I remove an HTML comment from a string using PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I tried:

```
echo preg_replace('<!--hello//-->','','<p>This is some text<!--hello//-->This is some more text</p>');
```

Trying to return

```
<p>This is some textThis is some more text</p>
```

But instead I got

```
<p>This is some text<>This is some more text</p>
```

Why do the brackets remain in the string?

Thanks for the help!

Edit: This question is not looking for the right regex to use...it's moreso why the function preg_replace is behaving weirdly.

Comment: You need to add regex delimiters, `'~<!--hello//-->~'`. Or just use `str_replace` if you plan to remove a fixed substring. See https://ideone.com/OlAXUY.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew! What is the purpose of those delimiters?

Comment: Regex delimiters show the boundaries between the pattern and the modifiers (flags, or options).

Comment: In your case, the problem is that leading/trailing `<` and `>`  are parsed as paired regex delimiters. Thus, you need to use more common ones, `/` or `~`, in addition to your *pattern*.

Comment: Ahhhh now I understand! I didn't realize that `<` and `>` were being treated as delimiters

Comment: Like @WiktorStribiżew said. You'll need boundaries: `/ regex / flags` or `~ regex ~ flags`. Next, regex has certain [special characters](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html) which need to be escaped if used as literal characters. Something to keep in mind :)

Comment: Yes, I was amazed that none of these characters needed to be escaped based on the list I found. Turns out the list didn't include delimiters.

Comment: @NickManning: as an aside, regex is absolutely not the way to edit html, use DOMDocument and DOMXPath to do that. This way you can avoid false positive, for example: `<script> var a='<!--hello//-->';</script>`